# Create a new array using elements from other arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am having 4 arrays like below

```
array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
array4 = ["10", "20", "30"];
```

By using the elements of these arrays I need to create another set of arrays like below

```
oneArray = ["one", "1", "a", "10"];
twoArray = ["two", "2", "b", "20"];
threeArray = ["three", "3", "c", "30"];
```

Is there any simple way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Use lodash:

```
array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
array4 = ["10", "20", "30"];

result = _.zip(array1, array2, array3, array
```

This should give you:

```
[
  ["one", "1", "a", "10"],
  ["two", "2", "b", "20"],
  ["three", "3", "c", "30"]
]
```

Comment: You will need to add the lodash library for this to work https://lodash.com/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's very simple

```js
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
const array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
const array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const array4 = ["10", "20", "30"];

const oneArray = [array1[0],array2[0],array3[0],array4[0]];
const twoArray = [array1[1],array2[1],array3[1],array4[1]];
const threeArray = [array1[2],array2[2],array3[2],array4[2]];
console.log([oneArray, twoArray, threeArray])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
const array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
const array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const array4 = ["10", "20", "30"];

const newArr = [array1, array2, array3, array4]
const oneArray= newArr.map((arr) => arr[0]);
const twoArray= newArr.map((arr) => arr[1]);
const threeArray= newArr.map((arr) => arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine arrays in one array and use `map`. This should work even your array size increase from 3 elements to more.

```js
const array1 = ["one", "two", "three"];
const array2 = ["1", "2", "3"];
const array3 = ["a", "b", "c"];
const array4 = ["10", "20", "30"];

const all = [array1, array2, array3, array4];
const [oneArray, twoArray, threeArray] = all[0].map((_, i) => all.map(arr => arr[i]));

console.log(oneArray);
console.log(twoArray);
console.log(threeArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. it will solve your problem.

```
    array1 = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six" ];
    array2 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"];
    array3 = ["a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "g"];
    array4 = ["10", "20", "30", "40", "50", "60"]
    array5 = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"]

    finalArray = [
    array1,
    array2,
    array3,
    array4,
    array5
    ];



 function joinNewArray(arrayList) {
            const combinedArray = [];
            let finalGeneratedArray = [];

            for(let i =0; i<= arrayList[0].length ; i++ ){

                for(let j = 0; j<= arrayList[0].length; j++){

                    if(arrayList[j]== undefined || arrayList[j][i] == undefined ) {
                         break;
                    }

                  finalGeneratedArray.push(arrayList[j][i]);       

                }  
                if(finalGeneratedArray.length > 0){
            combinedArray.push(finalGeneratedArray);
                }
            finalGeneratedArray = [];   

          }

      return  combinedArray;

    }

    const result =  joinNewArray(finalArray);
    console.log(result);
```